# Select all relevant qualities that apply to the Functionality of a coding responses

Tags: coding-style

a) Execution output that matches the output required by the prompt. b) Diligent unit testing. c) Checking For edge class d) Good variables names. e) lack of compilation errors

I need the answer with some sort of explaination

Answer (score 0):

right options are :-
1.Execution output that matches the output required by the prompt

2.Checking for edge cases

3.Lack of compilation errors